# how to prepend an element to an array when element is a key

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where each value is a an array.

What I want to do is simply write the array to a csv in the form of writer.writerow(myrow).

Why doesn't the following work:

```
for key,value in sorted(players.items()):
        writer.writerow( value.insert(0,key))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `writer.writerow(value.insert(0, key))`, that doesn't work because `value.insert(0, key)` returns `None`:

```
>>> value = [6, 7, 8]
>>> new = value.insert(0, 5)
>>> new
>>> print new
None
>>> value
[5, 6, 7, 8]
>>>
```

Instead, add one more line to your `for` loop:

```
for key,value in sorted(players.items()):
        value.insert(0, key)
        writer.writerow( value)
```

Basically, what you are doing is calling `writer.writerow(None)`; the above code will fix that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

because `list.insert` works "in-place". It returns `None` because it doesn't give a value, it just operates on the list itself.

Imagine this:

```
def multiply_by_three(number):
    global number
    three = 3 # magic numbers are bad, right? :)
    number = three * number
```

It doesn't return number, it just changes it wherever it lived. In in fact returns `None` since functions do that implicitly if they don't have a `return` statement.

So essentially you're doing:

```
for key,value in sorted(players.items()):
    writer.writerow(None)
```

If by `Array` you mean `list`, then you could do instead:

```
for key,value in sorted(players.items()):
    writer.writerow([key]+value)
```